# Git - system thinks commit is local changes

Tags: git, github

i am having a strange problem. I'm not advanced user of git, so i must done something wrong.

1) I have created an repository on Github, for now it has only branch - master.

2) I have cloned repository on my server using git clone ...

3) I submited a new commit and pushed it on Github

4) I have executed 'git pull' on server and he is displaying the next warning.

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

Those files are exactly those which i changed, commited and pushed on server. Why he is thinking it is locally changed?

any idea?

thank you!

Comment: Could you post the content of your `.gitattributes` file, if there is one?

Comment: What is the output of `git status`?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
git log
```

To check is your commit in history.

When you don't know what has been done use

```
git status
```

to check which files are changed

```
git diff
```

to see exact changes in files

And the rule of thumb is to use

```
git pull --rebase
```

--rebase will prevent branch history issues, it will put you changes on the top

More here https://git-scm.com/documentation